# WPF binding question

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datacontext

For example, I have:

MainWindows.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
            public List<Player> List;
            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                List = new List<Player>()
                           {
                               new Player() {Id = 1, Name = "Tom"},
                               new Player() {Id = 2, Name = "Bob"},
                               new Player() {Id = 3, Name = "Any"},
                           };
                comboBox1.DataContext = List;

            }

            public class Player
            {
                public string Name { get; set; }
                public int Id { get; set; }
            }
    }
```

XAML: `<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>`

How I can (need to) set List as a DataContext from the XAML? (and delete "comboBox1.DataContext = List" from the code-behind)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unless you're using MVVM u don't *need to* do that, but in any case, use can create the List as a property of the window like so

```
public List<Player> List {get;set;}
```

and then in XAML u can use RelativeSource to bind to the window:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=List, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window, Mode=FindAncestor}}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
```

alternatively, u can give a name to your window:

```
<Window .... x:Name="MyWindow" ..>
```

and then use ElementName in the binding, like so:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=List, ElementName=MyWindow}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Quick fix is setting your ComboBox's ItemsSource directly in code-behind (instead of DataContext), but in order to be able to use proper bindings you'll need a ViewModel or at least a XAML DataContext.

Also you should pick some more unique name than List for your List, like for example Players – it's good practice to use the plural form of the type of Objects in the List.